# How to include a js file in index.html while running a client server code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have following code for running server

server.js :

```
var http= require('http');
var fs= require('fs');
var file= fs.readFile("./public/index.html", function(error,html) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  } else {
    var server= http.createServer(function(req,rspn) {
      rspn.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
      rspn.write(html);
      rspn.end();
    });
    server.listen(8000);
  }
});
```

And my index.html and client.js files are in public folder. My index.html file is following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> WEBCAM </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id='request'>Request Camera</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have some code written in client.js. Now after running server.js if I open localhost:8000 in browser then I saw in console that in client.js same index.html code is getting copied. It is not reading the content of client.js
What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: You are reading before checking request URL and then sending it for every request. You need to define routes for different files. Thouhh for purpose of serving static files you can directly user http-server npm package.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solve your problem:

```
var http= require('http');
var fs= require('fs');
var server= http.createServer(function(req,rspn) {
      rspn.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
      fs.createReadStream("./public/index.html").pipe(rspn)
    }).listen(8000);
  }
});
```